# PHP variable to access variable within an array

Tags: php, arrays, reference

Not being used to php, I'm facing an issue with accessing arrays and its sub data.

```
$form['signatories']['signatory1'] = array(...);
```

I must create a "pointer" to the array created in the line above, I expected the following to work:

```
$cluster = $form['signatories']['signatory1'];
```

Testing I'm accessing the same "memory space" proves I'm wrong:

```
$cluster['signatory_name'] = array(...)
// $form['signatories']['signatory1'] has no elements
// $cluster has a sub element
```

Like cluster is a copy of the array I want it to point to.

How should I proceed? I tried using the "&" reference sign as mentioned in some blog, but that didn't help.

Thanks!
J.

Comment: Can you post the result of a `print_r($form);` to get things clearer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, assignment in PHP is by value, not by reference, except for objects.

If you want to pass a reference to the original array, you need to create a reference explicitly:

```
$cluster = &$form['signatories']['signatory1'];
```

See [assigning by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign) in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `=&` to assign by [reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.spot.php):

```
$cluster =& $form['signatories']['signatory1'];
```

Effectively this is two operations. The first is `&$form['signatories']['signatory1']` which gives you a reference to `$form['signatories']['signatory1']`. The second is `=` which obviously assigns the reference to `$cluster`.